# Google Sheet - get the cell reference of the cell with the custom function in

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a google sheets macro to get the row of the cell being called by the function.
Then I would like to get a range of cells on that row and check their values.

If I pass in a range I can just use that range, but I wanted to get the cell where the function is being called and just check the specific cells on that row instead.

Is this possible?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1]; // assume that the unmapped is the second sheet
  var w_row = 5;
  var rng = sheet.getRange('AH'+w_row+':AO'+w_row);

  console.log( 'sheet : '+sheet.getName() );
  console.log( 'values : '+rng.getValues() );
  console.log( 'row : '+rng.getRow() );
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It is unclear _what_ row number you want to get. Please explain your use case and see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that the code you show is part of a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

You can get a range that corresponds to columns `AH` to `AO` in the row where the custom function cell is like this:

```
/**
* Gets values in the same row.
* @customfunction 
*/
function myCustomFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const customFunctionCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  const row = customFunctionCell.getRow();
  const rangeA1 = `AH${row}:AO${row}`;
  const range = sheet.getRange(rangeA1);
  const values = range.getDisplayValues().flat().join(', ');
  return `The range is: ${rangeA1} and the values are ${values}`;
}
```

Comment: Hi

Thanks for the answer.
To ask for clarification - getActiveCell -> gets the active cell or the cell where the formula/function is being called from ?

I also found another post that says that the range when being called from the sheet; function(a:b)... the range is not passed as a range -> it is passed as range.getValues
I've updated my code to account for that, but would like to still get the row from the cell calling the formula.

Comment: The code above gets the _row number_ of the cell where the custom function resides, and demonstrates how to use the `row` variable for a couple of purposes.